# Fancybox - Open another popup when closing a popup

Tags: jquery, fancybox

This is my js code

```
        jQuery('.fancybox').fancybox({


            beforeLoad: function(current, previous) {

                document.getElementById("petition-form").reset();

                jQuery('#petition-form').show();

                jQuery('.petition-message').html("");

                jQuery('.petition-message').hide();

            },


            afterClose: function() {

                jQuery.fancybox.open('#cancelform');


            }


        }

        );
```

The second popup open when closing the first one, but the second one also get closed. I am using fancybox 2+ . I also get a js error TypeError: this.overlay is null .

Answer (score 2):

I experienced the same problem after upgrading to the latest version. A quick fix but not a solution is to add a short delay inside of your 'afterclose'. This seems to free up the overlay in time.

```
'afterClose':function () {
    setTimeout(func, 50);
    function func() {
        $.fancybox();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing:

```
...
afterClose: function() {
    jQuery.fancybox.open('#cancelform');
}
...
```

to

```
afterClose: function() {
    jQuery('#cancelForm').fancybox().trigger('click');
}
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aphjq/)

**Updated Code::**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        helpers: {
            overlay: null        
        },
        'afterClose': function() { 
            $("#cancelForm").fancybox().trigger("click");
        }
    });
});
```

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aphjq/2/)

Comment: Hi, The click trigger is working only when the second popup is a link , but in my case its a div

Comment: The second popup gets open but it get closes instantly . its shows this error in console "TypeError: this.overlay is null
this.overlay.width(width).height('100%');"<a class='fancybox' href='#petition-form-container'>Sign petition</a><a class='fancybox' href='#cancelForm'>feedback</a><div class="cancelForm" id="cancelForm" style="width:600px;display: none;">
 <h1>thank you for your feedback.</h1>
</div>
 <div class="petition-form pure-form" id="petition-form-container" style="width:250px;display: none;"> <div>

Comment: Sudhir, Its working...Thank you so much.. If possible can you tell me how the issue is resolved when we add the helper condition

Comment: @lajeeshk on trying to open second popup after closing first, fancybox was not able to get the overlay due to which second popup didnt get triggered, so we can set overlay to null so that the overlay gets disabled..!

Comment: Okay..So now the first popup doesn't have that grey background..but the second popup has. There is no way to get that grey background for the first popup also. Its not important, Im just asking